# Let $f(x)=\int_0^x \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{(x-t)^i}{i!}dt.$ Find the nth derivative $f^{(n)}x.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^x \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(x-t)^i}{i!}dt.$ Find the nth derivative $f^{(n)}x.$

Note that $x$ appears both sides in the integrand and in the limits, so we need to work carefully. Write $g_n (x,t) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{(x-i)^i}{i!}$ so that $f(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^x g_n (x,t)e^{nt}dt.$ By definition, $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^{x+h}g_n(x+h,t)e^{nt}dt - \displaystyle\int_0^x g_n(x,t) e^{nt}dt}{h}.$ Could anyone help me simplify this?

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: This is actually just a finite term polynomial so you can interchange the summation sign with the integral sign and apply Leibniz rule. It is more interesting if you want to see the limit as $n\to\infty$ but I leave it that up to your curiosity.

Comment: Where does the $e^{nt}dt$ in $f(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^x g_n (x,t)e^{nt}dt$ come from? Is that an error, or is it missing in your initial definition of $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $t =x-s$ in the integral:
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(x-t)^i}{i!}dt
= \int_0^x \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{s^i}{i!}ds 
$$
so that the integrand does not depend on $x$ anymore. Now differentiation becomes simple, e.g.:
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{x^i}{i!}
$$
etc.

Comment: @FredJefferson: Both the title and the first line of the question define $f(x)=\int_0^x \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{(x-t)^i}{i!}dt$ – am I overlooking something?

Comment: @FredJefferson: Actually I don't know where that comes from. I have asked the author for clarification.

Comment: I think the OP made a typo or something. It doesn't make any sense why the OP needed the term $e^{nt}.$

Answer (score 0):

In general
$$\int_{0}^{x} (x-t)^n \, dt = \left[ - \frac{(x-t)^{n+1}}{n+1} \right]_{0}^{x} =  \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
which can be used in the following way.
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_{0}^{x} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(x-t)^k}{k!} \, dt \\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e_{n}(x) - 1,
\end{align}
where $e_{n}(x)$ is the finite exponential function. This also shows that $f(0) = e_{n}(0) - 1 = 0$.

Now, using
$$D^{(m)} ( x^n ) = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} \, x^{n-m}$$
then
\begin{align}
f^{(m)}(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^{k-m}}{(k-m)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{x^{k-m}}{(k-m)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e_{n-m}(x).
\end{align}

In the case $m=n$ this becomes $f^{(n)}(x) = e_{0}(x) =1$.